# How to match a string of stray characters (matching no other regular expression) in flex?

Tags: regex, error-handling, flex-lexer

I'm trying to make a simple lexer with flex that reads integers and if it finds any characters that do not form an integer it should print the string of non-matching characters.

These are the patterns I've used along with the C code to execute if the pattern matches.

```
{INT}({DEL}|{ENTER}) { return INT;}   
{ENTER}              { printf("#End of line\n");}
{DEL}               
<<EOF>>              { printf("#End of file#\n"); exit(0);}
.                    { printf("Unrecognized characters: %s\n",yytext);
                      fprintf(yyout, "Unrecognized characters: %s\n",yytext);}
```

My problem is that when i use `.` then the lexer matches one character at a time. However if i use `.+` then the lexer will match everything along with the integers and regard everything as an error.

If i should show more code let me know. I'll give an example of what i get and what i want as an output from the lexer.

Example input file:

> 23 55
>
> 12asd
>
> @213

Example output file when using `.` :

> token=INT, value="23"
>
> token=INT, value="55
>
> Unrecognized characters: 1
>
> Unrecognized characters: 2
>
> Unrecognized characters: a
>
> Unrecognized characters: s
>
> Unrecognized characters: d
>
> Unrecognized characters: @
>
> token=INT, value="213"

Example output file when using `.+` :

> Unrecognized characters: 23 55
>
> Unrecognized characters: 12asd
>
> Unrecognized characters: @213

Desired output:

> token=INT, value="23"
>
> token=INT, value="55
>
> Unrecognized characters: 12asd
>
> Unrecognized characters: @213

Comment: Do your integers have to have whitespace/newline on both sides in order to be considered integers to be matched?

Comment: @aaron_world_traveler  no because that wouldn't read the first integer at the start of the file.

Comment: Sure, there's ways to match those cases though.  I can post a regex that matches all such integer strings if you want...

Comment: I think i could build such a regex..However if we suppose that i got that regular expression, what you are suggesting is to change {INT}{DEL}|{ENTER} to {DEL}|{ENTER}{INT}{DEL}|{ENTER}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer to my question after all.

The problem is that `.` contains spaces and tabs. Thereby when one uses `.+` it will eat everything along with tabs and spaces and consider every line as an error. Probably because .+ provides a longer match.

> [^ \t\n]+({DEL}|{ENTER})

This regular expression  will read everything apart from white-spaces until a white-space is read. If however the content of `[^ \t\n]+` is an INT this will not be the regular expression that will be matched. INT will be matched because it has a greater precedence.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt very highly that such a pattern exists. However you could just collect the single stray characters in your solution above and print/process them in one go with every matched non-stray token and at the end of the input. This involves reallocating a buffer of increasing size, potentially as big as the complete input.